# garbage collection in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For the below code, I am not able to clear the memory allocated for 'root' variable evan after 'del root' and gc.collect(). I understand that in python, garbage collection releases automatically. Is there any way I can clear it more?

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import os
import sys
from memory_profiler import profile
import gc
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



def f():
    with open('file.xml') as f:
        output_xml_str = f.read()
    root = ET.fromstring(output_xml_str)
    del root

@profile
def main():
    x = {}
    for i in xrange(10000):
        x[i] = i+1
    del x
    f()
    for i in range(12):
        gc.collect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

and here's profiling output

[image]

Comment: See the [Python Document on gc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html), pay special attention to leak and debug.

Comment: Have you checked `gc.get_referrers(root)` and `gc.garbage`? I would guess that either the former contains something other than `f`, or `root` is in the latter.

Comment: Also... does `file.xml` contain any cyclical references? It's not impossible for those to exist in XML (though parsers don't have to deal with them, I don't know whether Python's internal representation does), and the garbage collector can potentially have difficulty cleaning those up - you'd have to break the loop manually.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do much except calling `gc.collect()` plus you can adopt good practice style like you used `del` to tell the `GC` that you don't want it anymore so it will be deleted when `GC` will come around and do it's job.

You should use `numpy` for container like array which is more efficient in terms of memory management